# How to insert data into a table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Insert into the App.settings table the following values:

```
(99, DEFAULT, "horizontal", "2015-09-15 04:01:04")
```

I have a DATABASE called App with a settings table. I am trying to insert into the table but I can not seem to get it right.

My statement:

```
INSERT INTO App.settings
    VALUES(99, DEFAULT, "horizontal", "2015-09-15 04:01:04");
```

Am I doing it right? It says my answer is wrong.

```
mysql> DESC App.settings;
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id         | int(7)              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email_frequency | tinyint(2) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| layout          | varchar(70)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at      | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: In Standard SQL strings are single-quoted: `(99, DEFAULT, 'horizontal', '2015-09-15 04:01:04')`. Object names are double-quoted: `"App"."settings"`

Comment: What columns are in `App.settings`? Can you use `DESC App.settings` and show us the result? Also, what DBMS are you using? (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, MongoDB, ...)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `insert`, *always* list the columns in the table.  Second, the default string delimiter is the single quote in SQL rather than the double quote.

So I would expect to see:

```
INSERT INTO App.settings (col1, col3, col4)  -- your real column names here
    VALUES (99, 'horizontal', '2015-09-15 04:01:04');
```

Note that `col2` was removed from the `INSERT` and the `VALUES` because you seem to want a `DEFAULT` value.  Not all databases support that syntax.

Comment: Why _always_? If the table is not subject to change, I wouldn't say that it's absolutely necessary

Comment: @TwiN . . . Because people who are learning SQL should learn how to do it right.  If you are experienced and know when not to use column names, then you'll ignore the advice.  There is only one case where I do not list column names, and it is something of an outlier.  I *always* list column names for non-temporary tables.  I don't want changes in table structures to cause *unexpected* behavior in code.

Comment: This is the statement I use: INSERT INTO App.settings VALUES (99, DEFAULT, 'horizontal', '2015-09-15 04:01:04'); The error I get is [Error]: Task 1. Expected: Insert into the App.settings table the specified values. Try again.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ah, when in code, I definitely agree with you. We should always include the name of the columns. From his example, though, I thought it didn't look like he was trying to use it in code.

Comment: Maybe I have to use the ALTER keyword?

Comment: @RuskiCode No, you don't. The `ALTER` keyword is used for `ALTER`ing the table itself, not the content in that table (e.g. add/delete/modify the columns of the table; but not the values of the rows themselves).

Answer (score 0):

you are sure that all the fields of the tuple are there and if so, they are in the correct order if you are not entering all the fields of the tuple you should use the following form: `INSERT INTO App.settings(value, config, position, date ) VALUES(99, "DEFAULT", "horizontal", "2015-09-15 04:01:04");`

In the same order

> this is only an example i dont know the fields names you must be change for the you are using

Answer (score 0):

Like @GordonLinoff said, you should include the columns in your query. That way, you can also skip entering the `DEFAULT` value for `email_frequency`.

As for the mistake, it's most likely the double quotes that you're currently using instead of single quotes.

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO App.settings (user_id, layout, updated_at) 
    VALUES (99, 'horizontal', '2015-09-15 04:01:04');
```